# Is rsync really any faster on files that have changed?

Tags: performance, rsync

Why can't I trust rsync to be minimally as fast as cp?  (I'm ignoring negligible differences for overhead.)

It seems to me like rsync is fairly slow on files with no content difference, but a changed timestamp.

If I make a file:  cp -a testfile-100M destfile

And then I rsync them, I get what you would expect:

$ rsync -av testfile-100M destfile
sending incremental file list

sent 56 bytes received 12 bytes 8.00 bytes/sec
total size is 104857600 speedup is 1542023.53

But that's just because rsync is checking the size and the timestamp and skipping the file.  What if I just change the timestamp?

$ touch testfile-100M

$ rsync -av testfile-100M destfile sending incremental file list
testfile-100M

sent 104870495 bytes received 31 bytes 113804.15 bytes/sec
total size is 104857600 speedup is 1.00

Also note that even though the speedup is 1, the inital copy took about 1/4 the time to complete than the final rsync, even though the contents are exactly the same.  So what's going on here?  Is it just all the overhead of doing the comparisons?

If that's the case, then when does rsync ever provide a performance advantage?  Only when files are exactly the same on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the answer is that rsync does some extra steps in order to keep files in a consistent state, and not in a "partial-transferred" state while operating.  Using the `--inplace` option removes this overhead.

Answer (score 3):

For local files, if the size or mtime have changed, rsync by default just copies the whole thing without using its delta algorithm. You can turn this off with the `--no-whole-file` option, but for local copies this will typically be slower.

For the specific case of touching a file without changing it:

- If you give the `--size-only` option, it will assume that files that have the same size are unchanged.
- If you give the `--checksum` option, it will first hash the file to see if anything has changed, before copying it.

Comment: Even with "--size-only" rsync seems to take *forever* to build its incremental file list. Why? I can manually check the file sizes and which ones have changed *much* faster! What is it wasting time doing, and how do I turn these fancy features off? EDIT: Ah, never mind, I had the 'c' flag set by accident. Without the checksums it is very fast at this.

Answer (score 2):

When the source and destination are both locally mounted filesystems rsync just copies the file(s) if the timestamps or sizes don't match. Rsync wins where you have large files with small differences and they are on machines separated by a low bandwidth link.

EDIT:  Since someone felt the need to downvote this ancient answer...  As to why rsync on local files might be slower than cp, there does not seem to be any good reason.

Comment: Thanks.  That doesn't explain why cp was 4x faster than rsync on the local disk.  Sorry, I probably didn't make that point clear... I wanted to know why I couldn't trust rsync to be just as fast as cp (with some minor overhead for checking files first).  I might have to test to see if cp slows down as well when I copy over another file.  Maybe the performance issue is due to unlinking of the old file before copying over the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, for me rsync is about 4× faster than cp for copying to an external USB drive.